# Why Php FFmpeg exec() process stop my web app?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have my web app developed on azure. When I start an ffmpeg process with exec, if the file is larger than 50MB, it stops the web app until it finish to process the file. Why does that happens?

Comment: Because PHP executes one line and when finished executes the next etc..  You will need to launch it in the background.

Comment: Just to clarify AbraCadaver point. You notice it when a file is "over 50 Mb" only because that size takes enough for the process to notice the time needed to process it. PHP is not asynchronous and thus process one instruction at the time. As suggested by AbraCadaver, you could write a PHP script instead that is run in the background using CRON or any equivalent.

Comment: How you said i've noticed that is not the app but only the php code that stops..

Comment: But the problem is not only on the page that run the exec().  It locks all my php pages.

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough I programmed this for a customer myself some weeks ago.

1. You can use AJAX in front-end and start each convertion via a JS.
2. You can use a php "daemon"
   2.0 Start the program independently `php converter.php video1.mp4 >/dev/null 2>&1 &`
   2.1 You can start the normal script (via website), and it could restart itself as independent `php converter.php` (e.g. when a POST or GET is given) and the program will start itself in the script with `shell_exec('php converter.php daemon');` (for example) in the background. You then can check via AJAX or maybe a websocket if the process has finished.

Tips:

1. Use a `.lock`-file or something similar in case the program could start a second time without it being finished yet.
2. Use this repo `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg` https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg